# Devuelve undefined al recorrer un array con .some

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto que es el siguiente

```
const list = [
   {
     Warehouses: [
       {
         WarehouseId: "3BC",
         Express: false,
       },
     ],
   },
   {
     Warehouses: [
       {
         WarehouseId: "2ABC",
         Express: false,
       },
     ],
   },
 ];
```

Al intentar recorrer este arreglo para saber si el warehouse que tengo concuerda con unos de esos que tiene el objeto me retorna undefined.E probado con .map y el resultado es el mismo.

```
 const checkBranchOffice = (Warehouse) => {
    list.some((data) => {
      console.log(data.Warehouses[0])
      let idWarehouses = data.Warehouses[0];
      if (idWarehouses.WarehouseId === Warehouse) {
        console.log("true")
        return true;
      }
    });
  };

let test = checkBranchOffice("2ABC")
console.log(test)
```

Comment: Te falta un return delante de `list.some(...)`. Tu función no devuelve nada, el único return está en la función que le pasas a `some` como parámetro. Otra opción sería quitar las llaves de la función checkBranchOffice, para que se devuelva automáticamente el resultado de some: `Warehouse => list.some(data => data.Warehouses[0].wharehouseId === Warehouse)`

Comment: @PabloLozano Mil gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const list = [
   {
     Warehouses: [
       {
         WarehouseId: "3BC",
         Express: false,
       },
     ],
   },
   {
     Warehouses: [
       {
         WarehouseId: "2ABC",
         Express: false,
       },
     ],
   },
 ];

const checkBranchOffice = (checkedWarehouseId) => {
    return list.some((data) => {
        const warehouseData = data.Warehouses[0];
        if (warehouseData.WarehouseId === checkedWarehouseId) {
            return true;
        }
    });
};
const checkBranchOffice2 = (checkedWarehouseId) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
        const warehouseData = list[index].Warehouses[0];
        if (warehouseData.WarehouseId === checkedWarehouseId) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

console.log(checkBranchOffice("2ABC")); // true
console.log(checkBranchOffice("foo"));  // false
console.log(checkBranchOffice2("2ABC")); // true
console.log(checkBranchOffice2("foo"));  // false
```